# Bulk loading data into Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, nosql

Can anyone let me know how the fastest way to load bulk data , roughly something around 30 terabytes into Marklogic. Is Markstudio or mclp still an option in production environment. How others are loading Big data into Marklogic.

Answer (score 3):

MLCP should in principle work, but you might want to scale down transaction-size. 30 terabytes is a lot though, so make sure you have a MarkLogic cluster that is prepared for such a size, and have some patience. Run some test with a few small(er) sets first..

Answer (score 1):

When doing large data loads, the ability of the client to pump enough data to the cluster is often the bottleneck. Even with multiple threads on a multi-core host, you're still going to be competing for resources. If you happen to have an HDFS cluster, or other shared storage, we've found that you can get better parallelization by staging the data to HDFS and running a distributed mlcp job that writes directly from data nodes to MarkLogic D-nodes.